# ArrayFormula circular dependency detected

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to make a helper column but am stuck because if I'm doing it for every row it's working, but if I make it an array formula it errors.

For a single cell, the formula is like this:

```
=if(AND(len(G2)>0, len(F2)>0),
    if(G2=G1, I1+1, "1"),
    if(AND(len(G2)=0, len(F2)=0), "", I1+1)
)
```

and I make an array formula like so:

```
={"Bundle Helper"; arrayformula(if(AND(len(G3:G)>0, len(F3:F)>0),
    if(G3:G=G2:G, I2:I+1,"1"),
    if(AND(len(G3:G)=0, len(F3:F)=0), "", I2:I+1))
)}
```

As I understand it, the problem is because I need a row before to add value in column "i" **I1+1**, but because it's an array so it becomes a problem **I2:I+1**.

Is there any other way or solution to this problem?

**[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wPNYKbtbkaZ2LDrFq2RO_f13cfQeGcWsyhwS5VDkuvk/edit#gid=0)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F), COUNTIFS(F2:F, F2:F, ROW(F2:F), "<="&ROW(F2:F)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: sry im not clear enough about my question, but what i want is this number -> 1
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
2
3
4
1
1
2, i modified your formula into every cell into this =iF((LEN(G2)) * (LEN(F2)), IF(G2=G1, 1+I1, 1), ) its working on every cell, but i need it convert to arrayformula, is it possible?